Dirac delta identity using MeijerG
In https://functions.wolfram.com/14.03.26.0002.01, there's an identity given for DiracDeltausing MeijerG which even has a code snippet:
DiracDelta[x] == MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{}, {}}, 1 + x] /; Element[x, Reals] && x > -2

However, this code produces an error (in MMA v.14)
Out:= MeijerG[{{},{}},{{},{}},1+x] does not exist. Arguments are not consistent.

Any Idea why this is the case? I was convinced MMA can handle generalized functions just fine.

The "identity can't be correct because DiracDelta isn't restricted to x>-2

Isn't it meant as, the identity only holds for x>-2, and not that Dirac delta is defined only there? @UlrichNeumann
